# Adding Page Tab (issue)

Tags: facebook, canvas

Steps to Reproduce:

1. open https://developers.facebook.com/apps
2. create new app
3. filling mytabname exc.
4. save and wait several min.
5. i cannot see (in apps panel left) **View App Profile Page**

And i search my appname on search tool, i cannot found.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/315217388499608?browse=search_4ef5b73b545152863941310

Answer (score 1):

Go to your application and click `Edit settings`, then under 'Select how your app integrates with Facebook' make sure you select `App on Facebook`.

Comment: just wanna add tab to page dudes, i cannot see Wiew app profile. 
----------------------------------
By February 1, 2012, we are removing App Profile Pages. You can migrate Likes and the Vanity URL of this Page to an existing Facebook Page with the same name and of Product/App category.
----------------------------------------------

and then how i add my tab to my page? any idea? thank u

Comment: Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/, select your app and click `Edit settings`, under `Select how your app integrates with Facebook` select `Page Tab` and volia.